# How to add a number to a column in PHP and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

If the value is 5 I want to add +1 and the result is 6.

```
<?php
    $db = new PDO ( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database;charset=utf8', 'sunyamacs', 'asd123123');
    $db->setAttribute ( PDO::ATTR_ORACLE_NULLS, PDO::NULL_TO_STRING );
    $qry = $db->prepare ( "UPDATE user_data SET value = :value" );
    $qry->bindParam ( ':value', $db_data ['value'] );
    $db_data ['value'] = $db_data ['value'] + 1;
?>
```

This is not work but how to do it work?

Comment: What sql query generated from your coding?

Answer (score -1):

Use SQL for that:

```
UPDATE user_data SET value = value + 1 WHERE value = '5'
```

Comment: This is the right way to do it, although I don't think the OP literally meant for the WHERE clause to be there, I think that was just an example.

Comment: That's why in the first example I didn't wrote the WHERE statement being the reason of downvoting..